# Sending JSON from Javascript to PHP Server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I want to send JSON from javascript to PHP server vice versa, but i got exception `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` while get data from server.

I have tried to validate JSON output on [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) and my JSON is valid.
Here are JSON I would expected from server :

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4,
    "e": 5
}
```

and JSON which I sent to server :

```
{"counter":"123"}
```

Here are my code :

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/debug/json.php',
      data: {json: JSON.stringify(obj)}, 
      dataType: 'json'
  })
  .done( function( data ) {
      console.log('done');
      console.log(data);
  })
  .fail( function( data ) {
      console.log('fail');
      console.log(data);
  });
```

when obj is

```
var obj = {"counter":counter};
```

and on server-side (php)

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json_decode = json_decode($json, true); 
    $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5); 
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Request header

```
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 36
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response Header

```
Date: Thu, 22 Jun 2017 04:11:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.7
Content-Length: 31
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

I think problem comes from my PHP Script, but when i tried to access directly from URL its work like a charm. I got status code 200 but the `response error`. What I missed? thank you.

Comment: `data: {json: JSON.stringify(obj)}` - well, that looks like you want to send JSON which has JSON within it

Comment: @JaromandaX var obj= {"counter":counter}; I think problem comes from server when returned respond.

Comment: is the problem coming from `echo json_encode($arr);` or `echo json_encode($json_decode );` ?

Comment: @guradio Firstly, I used `$arr` to test directly from web browser. However, it isn't a problem.

Comment: i know it isnt the problem because the array looks ok maybe the problem is when you use the data from `json_decode `.

Comment: @guradio nope, it still problem even though commenting json_decode.